# jQuery object plugin is not persistant

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to extend a jquery element with custom properties and functions so I can track my elements and get their custom properties anytime.

at the moment I have done this:

```
 jQuery.fn.designerElement = function (tpl, cls) {
      this.__template = tpl
      this.des__class = cls;
      this.compile = function () {
          this.html(this.__template(this));
          return this;
      }

      return this;
  };

  var template = Handlebars.compile(
      '<div id="' + +new Date() + '" class="{{des__class}}"></div>'
  );

  var el = $('<div></div>').designerElement(template, "form-container");

  el.attr('id', "test");

  el.compile();

  $('body').append(el);
```

Now if I call `$('#test').compile()` it say says the method is undefined.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorvan/HLVj4/

To explain my context, I need the methods and properties available directly on the object for some dataBindings to work, thats why i can't use `.data()`. It seemed to me jquery plugin  would be the best approach but I am definitly missing something here.

So just to be clear I would need to be able to access properties like this: `$('#test').__template` as well as functions.

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already know what is going on but here's a short explanation: With `$('#test')` you are creating a new jQuery object. It contains the same element but you are defining properties for the jQuery object, not the element. So what you are asking is if there is a way to add the functionality to the element but with the jQuery object attached. In jQuery `data()` can after all be used to do this:

```
jQuery.fn.designerElement = function (tpl, cls) {
    this.__template = tpl
    this.des__class = cls;
    this.compile = function () {
        this.html(this.__template(this));
        return this;
    }
    this.data('this', this);
    return this;
};
```

And retrieve that object with:

```
var test = $('#test').data('this');
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HLVj4/2/)

Another solution is to store all these objects in a globally available array or JSON object.

Comment: thanks for you time @jazZRo! Unfortunatly, as I said in my question, `.data` doesnt work for me because it has a getter ans setter functions to access it and my bindings (ember) need a fully synthetised property. I really hopped there would be some way to attach properties to the element itself with JQuery. seems like the later solution will have to do. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: In JavaScript it's possible to extend an element's functionality by using it's prototype property. I've never done that so I can't advise on that. To me too, using a global array or JSON object looks like the way to go.

Comment: Your second solution is definitely the best I could work with. I tried attaching to the element using `$(el)[0]` but it seems jQuery looses ownPropertie's on DOM manipulation.